# Change "Done" button in Android numeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I have an EditText in Android configured for the number keyboard, and I would like the keyboard's button to say "next", while mine is saying "done".
How can I change that?
I already tried:

```
   <com.innovattic.font.FontEditText
   style="@style/CadastroTextBoxStyle"
   android:hint="CEP"
   android:id="@+id/etCEP"
   android:inputType="number"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android.imeOptions="actionNext" />
```

And also this:

```
    etCEP.setImeActionLabel("Next", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

But it still says done.
What else can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I think I've seen this answered around on the SO community...

Comment: For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22935932/995891 -> try a different phone, softkeyboard, they decide if they like to display something different. All Ime options are just "wishes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in *[Specifying the Input Method Type](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action)*, you do **not** need to call [TextView.setImeActionLabel(CharSequence, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeActionLabel(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) and you have to instead just provide a [android:imeOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) value such as `actionSend` or `actionNext` in XML attributes to change the label accordingly.

This is not working for you because you have mistyped `:` as `.` in your attributes. Switching those out should fix your issue in no time.

Comment: hahha sorry about that... strange that Eclipse didn't point out the  obvious TYPO. Thanks.