# What is imeActionId in android EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I cannot figure out what imeActionId does in EditText. I red android developer documentation which says

`Supply a value for EditorInfo.actionId used when an input method is connected to the text view.`

and I have no idea what does it mean?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753910/behaviour-of-imeoptions-imeactionid-and-imeactionlabel)

Comment: imeActionid is for identify edit text action like action search, action done , action next, etc..

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753910/behaviour-of-imeoptions-imeactionid-and-imeactionlabel